# evaluate the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ of $(\cos x-1)/x$ without l'Hopital's rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I know with l'Hopital's rule it becomes $-\sin(x)$ which has the limit $0$.
However, I have been wondering how to evaluate this limit without l'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Are you able to use the fact that the derivative of $\cos x$ is $-\sin x$? Because that limit is literally the limit definition of the derivative $\cos'(0)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT**
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x} & = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{(\cos(x)-1)(\cos(x)+1)}{x(\cos(x)+1)}\\\\
& = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos^{2}(x)-1}{x(\cos(x)+1)} = -\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin^{2}(x)}{x(\cos(x)+1)}
\end{align*}

Then make use of the fundamental limit
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to do
without using
$\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}
\to 1
$
so I won't try.

Here is one way using that.

$1-\cos(x)
=2\sin^2(x/2)
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{\cos(x)-1}{x}
&=\dfrac{-2\sin^2(x/2)}{x}\\
&=\dfrac{-\sin^2(x/2)}{x/2}\\
&=-\dfrac{\sin^2(x/2)}{(x/2)^2}(\dfrac{x}{2})\\
&\to -\dfrac{x}{2}\\
&\to 0\\
\end{array}
$

Note that this
also shows the more precise result
$\dfrac{\cos(x)-1}{x^2}
\to -\dfrac12
$.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos x =1-\dfrac{x^{2}}{2}+...=1+o(x)$. Hence $\frac {\cos\,x -1} x \to 0$ as $x \to 0$,