# How do you evaluate this limit - $\lim_{n \to 0}\frac{cos(n)-1}{n}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How do you prove that $$\lim_{n \to 0}\frac{\cos(n)-1}{n}$$
equals to $0$? I can't use L'Hôpital's rule because when differentiting cosine using $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\cos(x+h)-\cos(x)}{h}$$
we get that exact limit at some point. I assume we have to use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Use this [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/77z8ffeoet), small angle approximation, or the geometric proof.

Comment: In the definition of differentiation of cosine, can you simply choose $x=0$ and use $h=n$? Then you will get the answer by using the derivative of $\cos(x)$ is $-\sin(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: @user387147 As the asker points out, how would you know that the derivative of $\cos$ is $-\sin$ if you don't already know this limit?

Comment: Please close as a duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278264/evaluate-the-limit-as-x-approaches-0-of-cos-x-1-x-without-lhopitals-r

Comment: Does this answer your question? [evaluate the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ of $(\cos x-1)/x$ without l'Hopital's rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278264/evaluate-the-limit-as-x-approaches-0-of-cos-x-1-x-without-lhopitals-r)

Comment: Use L'Hospital Rule.

Comment: @BokaPeer look at the question, we cannot because that would using circular reasoning because of the question explanation.

Comment: Thanks. My bad. I did not read the problem statement completely. Sorry about that.

Comment: This is the definition of $\cos'(0)$.  If you do not already know $\cos'(0)$, then L'Hôpital does not help.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $|n|<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Then

\begin{eqnarray}
\sqrt{(1-\cos(n))^2+\sin^2(n)}&<&\vert n\vert\\
\sqrt{2(1-\cos(n))}&<&\vert n\vert\\
\frac{1-\cos(n)}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-\cos(n)}}&>&\frac{1-\cos(n)}{\vert n\vert}>0\\
\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos(n)}}{\sqrt{2}}&>&\frac{1-\cos(n)}{\vert n\vert}>0
\end{eqnarray}

Now apply the 'squeeze' theorem to the limit at $0$.

[image: unit circle]

Answer (score 0):

1. 

$$L=\lim_{n\to 0}\frac{cos(n)-1}n$$
2.$cos(n)\sim1-\frac {n^2}2, n\to 0$:
$$L=  \lim_{n\to 0}\frac{1-\frac {n^2}{2}-1}{n}=   \lim_{n\to 0}-\frac{n}{2}=\frac{0}{2}=0$$